# What is the benefit of comparing constant and variable with constant on the left?

Tags: php, c++, if-statement

Can anyone explain what is the benefit of comparing constant and variable with constant on the left e.g.

```
if (0 == variable)
```

Instead of

```
if (variable == 0)
```

Comment: To avoid accidental assignment, `if (variable = 0)`. If the constant is on the left-hand side, then it would be a syntax error: `if (0 = variable)`

Comment: Is it a coincidence that your avatar is Yoda? Anyway, compile with `-Wall` (or the equivalent for your compiler) and don't bother with this awful convention.

Answer (score 0):

If you say

```
if (variable == 0)
```

you are under the risk of omiting one `=` and saying

```
if (variable = 0)
```

which will set the variable `variable` to `0`.

So putting `0` to the left makes it more typo-safe, because `0 = variable` won't be able to set any value to the variable.